# Referencing a previous row value for an arithmetic calculation in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2 and new to relational database. I need to run a simple calculation but the calculation involves using a previous row value.

Example:

```
(Value of X) / ((Value of Y at time t + Value of Y at time t-1) / 2)
```

Example:

```
select (x/[(y@time,t + y@time,t-1)/2]) as 'Value'
from datatable
```

```
select ((c.ACHQ)/(c.RECTQ(row:n) + c.RETQ(row:n-1))/2) as 'AR'
from co_ifndq c
where c.GVKEY in 
(select GVKEY 
    from spidx_cst
    where DATADATE = '2012-03-12'
    and INDEXID = '500')
and c.DATAFMT = 'std'
and c.DATADATE > '1990-12-30'
order by c.GVKEY, datadate desc
```

Comment: Put some rows of the table here please. And how do you identity the previous moment?

Comment: How do you want to handle the calculation for the first record in the series (where there will be no previous row)?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to make a calculation base on a date difference and not really on a row order, right?

If so, if you have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(
    ACHQ float ,
    RECTQ float,
    DATE datetime)

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES    (100,10,'20100101')
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES    (200,20,'20110101')
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES    (300,30,'20120101')
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES    (400,40,'20130101')
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES    (500,50,'20140101')
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES    (600,60,'20150101')
```

you can do something like this

```
SELECT
    ((c.ACHQ)/(c.RECTQ + cPreviousYear.RECTQ)/2) as 'AR'
FROM
    YourTable c
        LEFT JOIN YourTable cPreviousYear
            ON YEAR(c.Date) - 1 = YEAR(cPreviousYear.Date)
```

I simplified the calculation just to show that you can link the table to itself directly to the row with the wanted date difference and then calculate the value. you can even use `ON DATEADD(y, -1, c.Date) = cPrevious.Date` if you want the real date diference

Sorry if I missed the point.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x, y and t are all on the same table, try:

```
;with cte as (
select m.*, row_number() over (order by t) rn from mytable)
select t1.t, t1.x / ((t1.y + t0.y)/2) as [value]
from cte t1
left join cte t0 on t0.rn = t1.rn-1
```

EDIT: based on the query supplied:

```
;with cte as (
select c.*, row_number() over (partition by c.GVKEY order by c.DATADATE) rn 
from co_ifndq c
where c.GVKEY in 
(select GVKEY 
 from spidx_cst
 where DATADATE = '2012-03-12' and INDEXID = '500')
and c.DATAFMT = 'std'
and c.DATADATE > '1990-12-30'
)
select t1.GVKEY, t1.DATADATE, t1.ACHQ / ((t1.RETQ + t0.RETQ)/2) as [value]
from cte t1
left join cte t0 on t1.GVKEY = t0.GVKEY and t0.rn = t1.rn-1
order by t1.GVKEY, t1.datadate desc
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer.. so elaborated the question with some of the code.. the select is obviously not correct but rather just a simplification(example) of what I need to do..

Comment: sorry and this is the second line after the select statement

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by c.gvkey order by c.GVKEY) as 'Year Number',

Comment: thus I need to take this years value and last years value and divide them by two (for the denominator)

Comment: @user1129988: See the updated answer. You still haven't explained how you want to handle the calculation for the first record in the series (where there will be no previous row).

Comment: the dates are in descending order.. so the first row 2012 and then 2011 and so on... thus, the issue would be the last row before the partition to the next gvkey

Comment: @user1129988: So how do you want to derive your value on the last row before the partition to the next key, given that Value of Y at time t-1 will be null?