# Insert Ratio of 2 rows in the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have to get ratio of 2 rows and insert it as an additional row in the same table in SQL Server. Here is an example.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID INT, Value1 VARCHAR(20), Value2 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #TEST 
VALUES (1, 100, 200), (2, 200, 400)
```

I want to insert a record `(3, 0.5, 0.5)` in the table where the values for `Value1` and `Value2` is the ratio of the previous 2 rows.

Can you please point me to how this can be done using a SQL query?

Comment: This feels like you could easily run into concency issues if you aren't careful. Are you wanting to `INSERT` all 3 rows at the same time, or are the other 2 already there and you want to get their values and then work out the "ratio"? By Ratio, do you actually mean the value of the 1st row divided by the 2nd as well?

Comment: I have inserted the other 2 rows  in an earlier insert statement. So the values are already there. I am trying to work the ratio. By ratio, I mean value of row 1 divided by value in the second row.

Comment: Why do you use `varchar(20)` data type for `Value1` and `Value2` columns?

Comment: In case then need to divide `'abc'` by `'def'`? :)

Answer (score -1):

Use Row number for airthmatics on rows in sql.

have a look on this link
[Referencing a previous row value for an arithmetic calculation in SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819898/referencing-a-previous-row-value-for-an-arithmetic-calculation-in-sql-server-200)